# Prolog: removing all elements that occur in list A from list B

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

I'm trying to define a predicate "delete(L1, L2, L3)" that is valid when L3 equals L2 minus any of these elements that are contained in L1. E.g. delete([1], [1,2,3], X) => would unify for X = [2,3]. My code is as follows:

```
isNonElement(_, []).
isNonElement(X, [Y|Z]) :- X \= Y, isNonElement(X,Z).

delete(_, [], []).
delete(Y, [X|W], Z) :- \+(isNonElement(X, Y)), delete(Y, W, Z).
delete(Y, [X|W], [X|Z]) :- isNonElement(X, Y), delete(Y, W, Z).
```

However it seems not to work for every test case. Can anyone help me out on what could be wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

P.S. I can't tell the cases for which my predicate doesn't work correctly since it's tested by a school system which doesn't tell me which test cases it failed for.

Comment: Minus *any* or minus *all*. Your example is only of one element, so it's ard to tell what you're after in the general case. Also *do not* use `delete` as a predicate name. It's already taken by a library predicate. Use something more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **very close**!

One remaining problem is that you are applying a perfectly sound logical reasoning to predicates that do not admit such a reading. Your code works exactly as intended if you simply apply the following extremely straight-forward changes:

1. instead of `(\=)/2`, use `dif/2`
2. instead of `\+(isNonElement(X, Y))`, simply write: `member(X, Y)`.

The first change is always advisable: It typically makes your programs usable in more directions. The second change avoids the use of impure negation by using a pure predicate instead.

In total, we now have:

```
isNonElement(_, []).
isNonElement(X, [Y|Z]) :- dif(X, Y), isNonElement(X,Z).

delete(_, [], []).
delete(Y, [X|W], Z)     :- member(X, Y), delete(Y, W, Z).
delete(Y, [X|W], [X|Z]) :- isNonElement(X, Y), delete(Y, W, Z).
```

Now check this out: First, your test case:

```
?- delete([1], [1,2,3], X).
X = [2, 3] ;
false.
```

Works as expected!

Second, a case with a variable for `L2`:

```
?- delete([], L2, []).
L2 = [] ;
false.
```

This seems also very nice.

Third, another variable:

```
?- delete([X], [1,2,3], Ls3).
X = 1,
Ls3 = [2, 3] ;
X = 2,
Ls3 = [1, 3] ;
X = 3,
Ls3 = [1, 2] ;
Ls3 = [1, 2, 3],
dif(X, 3),
dif(X, 2),
dif(X, 1) ;
false.
```

Note now the different possibilities for `X`, and how `dif/2` is used in answers to express that `X` must be *different* from certain integers in this case.

The use of impure predicates *precludes* such more general uses, and your grading system possible tries such cases too.

Note that you can of course easily implement `member/2` yourself. It is one of the most straight-forward relations. However, note also that `delete/3` is terribly named: An *imperative* always implies a particular direction of use, but the relation we are considering here also admits many other usage modes!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Replacing the negation of isNonElement by member fixed it. I'm not allowed to use predefined predicates though so I'll just rewrite it. As for the name of the predicate it was the choice of my course teacher and I'm not allowed to change it, but I agree. Again thank you for helping out :)

Comment: Great! Note that your initial solution already used the predefined predicates `(\+)/1` and `(\=)/1`, so take such requirements with a grain of salt. To see some of the differences between versions, consider for example the following query: `?- delete([X], [a], Z)`. With the initial version, you get `Z = []` which is correct *if* `X` is `a`, but wrong otherwise! If you use `member/2` instead of the unsound negation, you get: `X = a, Z = []`, which is at least a *correct* solution. Nevertheless, it is *incomplete*, because the other solution is `Z = [a], dif(X, a)`. Only `dif/2` gives you this!